# Reset counter in select after 5 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, counter

Table

```
Id  SomeValue
 1  Header1
 4  Header9
 7  Header5
 8  Header2 
 9  Header5 
12  Header4 
13  Header9 
14  Header7
```

Expected output

```
Id  SomeValue Counter
 1  Header1      1
 4  Header9      2
 7  Header5      3
 8  Header2      4
 9  Header5      5
12  Header4      1
13  Header9      2
14  Header7      3
```

Current output: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fd27/12). As you can see in fiddle, the counter is fine but it doesn't reset the count after 5 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator (`%`) to reset the count. You just need to explicitly treat zeros:

```
SELECT Id, SomeValue, CASE counter WHEN 0 THEN 5 ELSE counter END
FROM   (SELECT Id, SomeValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) % 5 AS counter
        FROM   Table1) t
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fd27/17/0) with your data attached.